# Как спозиционировать элементы в flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть заголовок магазина, и надо поисковую строку разместить посередине, корзину/аккаунт справа.
Но, `justify-self` результата не дает, а `margin-left: auto;` просто не позволяет поставить поиск. строку посередине, как мне расположить все это с помощью flex-box?

```
<header>
    <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="res/plaza-logo.png" alt="logo.png" height="49.8" width="204"></a>
    <div class="search-box"><input type="search"></div>
    <a class="shopping-cart" href="#"><img src="res/mini-ico/cart.png" alt="cart.png"></a>
    <a class="account" href="#"><img src="res/mini-ico/acc.png" alt="acc.png"></a>
</header>

header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.search-box input{
    justify-self: center;
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
.account{

}
.shopping-cart{
    justify-self: flex-end;
    margin-left: auto;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде, чем приступать к работе, советую ознакомится с [этим](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container).

Собственно, решение:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

`justify-content` указывает, как обрабатывать свободное место. В нашем случае мы говорим, что первый и последний элементы должны касаться краёв родителя, а свободное место внутри распределяется равномерно между элементами (то есть внутренние блоки, сколько бы их ни было, встанут на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга).